# Cuboid Optimalization Quest

Tags: geometry, functional-analysis

We have cuboid, which volume is $V = abc =60cm^3$. Find minimum if:

- field of the side walls cost $1j/cm^2$
- field of top wall cost $2j/cm^2$
- field of the base wall cost $3j/cm^2$

How to create some function $f(x,y,z)$ to designate minimum cost?

Comment: Hint: Make a sketch of the cuboid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let x,y and z be the width, length and hight of the cuboid. There are two side walls with the area xy and two side walls with the area zy. Therefore the costs for these walls are $2\cdot xz+2\cdot zy$. The top wall has the area xy. The costs are $2\cdot xy$. The cost of the base wall is $3\cdot xy$

Therefore the cost function is

$C(x,y,z)=2xz+2zy+2xy+3xy=2xz+2zy+5xy$

It is also known that $xyz=60$. Solving for $z$ gives $z(x,y)=\frac{60}{xy}$

Putting $z(x,y)$ in $C(x,y,z)$

$C(x,y)=\frac{120}{x}+\frac{120}{y}+5xy$

To optimize the costs we have to calculate the partial derivatives w.r.t $x$ and $y$ and set them equal to zero.

Then use the two equations to calculate the values for $x$ and $y$. Finally $z$ can be calculated by using the relation $z=\frac{60}{xy}$.

Comment: @grisza12 You´re welcome.

Comment: I found one more solution using Lagrange multipliers. $f(x,y,z)=2xz+2zy+5xy+\lambda(xyz-60)$

Comment: @grisza12 This is an equivalent method for this problem. I posted the method without  the langrange multiplier, because I didn´t know what your mathematical knowledge is.

Comment: Yes, I think but don't remember Lagrange method;p. I could solve your's method ealier but i hadn't got idea I'm a little embarrassed:) btw thx